# How to write update query with max value of a field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to execute this query but I am getting error. How can I run this type of query?

```
UPDATE `user` 
SET id = (SELECT (MAX(t.id)+1) as id FROM `user` as t)
WHERE id='';
```

Error message is:

```
[SQL]UPDATE `user`  SET id = (SELECT (MAX(t.id)+1) as id FROM `user` as t) WHERE id='' LIMIT 1; 
[Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'user' for update in FROM clause
```

My table scenario is

```
--------------
|User        |
--------------
| id  | name |
--------------
| 101 | A    |
--------------
|     | B    |
--------------
|     | C    |
--------------
|     | D    |
--------------
```

I want to update like this

```
--------------
|User        |
--------------
| id  | name |
--------------
| 101 | A    |
--------------
| 102 | B    |
--------------
| 103 | C    |
--------------
| 104 | D    |
--------------
```

Comment: You should use auto increment field for your user id. If you'll run 2 queries in the same time you might get 2 users with the same id.

Comment: In general, this kind of 'solution' should be avoided.

Comment: error massage added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables to achieve ur need.

```
set @rownum:=101;
update user set id = @rownum:=@rownum+1 where id is null
```

[**Check Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e86f62/1)

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I tried you query but got error. error is
[Err] 1221 - Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT

Comment: yes your 2nd query is worked. But first query set the same value for all.

Comment: Dont use first query. Wait i'll remove it. Kindly Accept/Vote the answer if it helped you so that others can refer the same:)

Comment: It works but not exactly what I want. In your query I must need to know the max value and need to enter max value. I already vote on your answer. But I am waiting for actual answer. If I won't get better answer than you then I will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: OK fine. i think you can use `set @rownum = (select MAX(id) FROM test);` instead of `set @rownum:=101;` to get the maximum value. Or even `SELECT @rownum := MAX(id) FROM test ;`

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Maxid integer
SELECT @Maxid = ISNULL(MAX(t.id),0)+1 as id FROM user t
UPDATE user
SET id = @Maxid
WHERE id='' LIMIT 1;
```

I hope it'll helps you.

Comment: I am getting error in this query. 
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare [at]Maxid integer